# How to change the identifier for UIBarButton dynamically in Swift?

Tags: swift, ios8, uibarbuttonitem, identifier

I have an IBOutlet which conatins the timer code and play button linked to it. I want to change the play button to pause button. Play button is present at the bottom which is added on right side of tool bar with flexible space seperators.

Below is the code:

```
IBOutlet var pauseButton: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBAction func playButton(sender: AnyObject) {

timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: ("counter"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

 pauseButton.image = UIImage(named: "tick")

}
```

Comment: just change the title of the button programmatically and include and if statement: if button.title is equal to play then do something else do something play should do. Or you could put a pause button right behind it and then hide the play button as soon as it presses unhide be pause button etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using:

```
@IBAction func pauseButton(sender: AnyObject) {

timer.invalidate()

pauseButton.image = UIImage(named: "tick")

}
```

Make sure you connect the button to this action. Note that this is not an outlet connection but an action.

Comment: this part of code should go in IBOutlet playButton method , because i need to change play button to pause button at the same location.

Comment: I'm sorry, but `@IBAction` is needed in this case. You need to activate something. '@IBOutlet' does not have any methods.